# C# - Escribir en app.config y que persistan los cambios

Tags: c#, app.config

No logro modificar en tiempo de ejecución una clave definida en mi archivo de configuración (app.config) y que el cambio quede guardado para cuando vuelva a ejecutar mi aplicación la próxima vez.

Si chequeo los valores en tiempo de ejecución veo que efectivamente se modifican, pero cuando reviso el archivo de configuración no veo el cambio.

```
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.AppSettings.Settings["MiClave"].Value = "NuevoValor";
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

No logro entender que me está faltando.

Comment: a que te referis cuando decis que revisas el archivo? estas dentro del compilador o ya es un ejecutable en otra ruta?

Comment: Abro el app.config dentro del mismo visual studio, en el explorador de soluciones. Ahí no veo reflejado el cambio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las configuraciones en un ejecutable no se almacenan en el `app.config`. Mira en el archivo `TuAplicacion.exe.config`,ahi deberías ver los cambios

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora si veo reflejado el cambio.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema y llegue a esta pregunta yo accedia con el properties.settings y no me funciono, ahora aplique tu codigo tal cual y me marca referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia a un objeto en la linea config.AppSettings.Settings["MiClave"].Value = "NuevoValor"; que crees que pueda ocasionar esto?

Comment: Quiere decir que en el archivo de configuracion no existe una definicion para "MiClave"